Django app failing to get deployed on Azure web service
I have a Django app that was running without issues till 2 days back on Azure. I then added some Azure OAI code using semantic-kernel and since then haven't been able to complete the deploy step of github actions workflow to deploy the app. To use semantic-kernel, I had to update to python 3.11 from python 3.8 on Azure. The deployment runs for about 40 mins and then errors out.
From docker logs, I see the following issue: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2024-12-30T01:12:32.6106267Z Using packages from virtual environment antenv located at /home/site/wwwroot/antenv.
2024-12-30T01:12:32.6117557Z Updated PYTHONPATH to '/opt/startup/app_logs:/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages'
2024-12-30T01:12:35.1840122Z [2024-12-30 01:12:35 +0000] [84] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 23.0.0
2024-12-30T01:12:35.3134084Z [2024-12-30 01:12:35 +0000] [84] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (84)
2024-12-30T01:12:35.3205313Z [2024-12-30 01:12:35 +0000] [84] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2024-12-30T01:12:35.3321195Z [2024-12-30 01:12:35 +0000] [89] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 89
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4238708Z [2024-12-30 01:12:35 +0000] [89] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4473148Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4475461Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.10/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 608, in spawn_worker
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4476786Z     worker.init_process()
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4477986Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.10/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in init_process
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4479379Z     self.load_wsgi()
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4480603Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.10/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 147, in load_wsgi
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4481752Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4484237Z                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4485531Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.10/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4486749Z     self.callable = self.load()
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4487911Z                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4489069Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.10/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 57, in load
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4490218Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4491827Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4493529Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.10/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 47, in load_wsgiapp
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4496151Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4497571Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4498724Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.10/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 370, in import_app
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4503737Z     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4505133Z           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4507753Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.10/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4509384Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4510611Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4511876Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4513103Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4571053Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4572360Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4573594Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4574752Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4575942Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/<my_app>/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4577090Z     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4578220Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2024-12-30T01:12:35.4888669Z [2024-12-30 01:12:35 +0000] [89] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 89)
2024-12-30T01:12:35.7610862Z [2024-12-30 01:12:35 +0000] [84] [ERROR] Worker (pid:89) exited with code 3
2024-12-30T01:12:35.7619628Z [2024-12-30 01:12:35 +0000] [84] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
2024-12-30T01:12:35.7622636Z [2024-12-30 01:12:35 +0000] [84] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

from Kudo logs, I see that the deployment is stuck at
2024-12-30T02:54:34.5926086Z Activating virtual environment...
2024-12-30T02:54:34.6393062Z Running pip install...
2024-12-30T03:33:42.8129357Z ..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

I have tried several ideas listed in different threads such as specifying the sys.path in wsgi.py or creating a new github deployment but no luck.
Any further ideas on what I can try out to fix this issue?
Additional information: - here is the requirements.txt file content. This works fine even if I try to install using all packages listed here on a local machine.
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiosignal==1.3.1
annotated-types==0.7.0
anyio==4.4.0
asgiref==3.5.0
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==23.1.0
azure-core==1.32.0
azure-identity==1.19.0
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
chardet==5.2.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.11
cloudevents==1.11.0
colorama==0.4.6
cryptography==36.0.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
Deprecated==1.2.15
deprecation==2.1.0
distro==1.9.0
django==4.0.2
django-betterforms==1.2
django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus==4.0.0
django-bootstrap-icons==0.7.6
django-bootstrap4==21.2
django-crispy-forms==1.14.0
django-multi-form-view==2.0.1
django-rest-authtoken==2.1.4
django-shapeshifter==18.9.23
djangorestframework==3.13.1
dnspython==2.6.1
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
fontawesomefree==5.15.4
frozenlist==1.3.3
grpcio==1.64.1
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==1.0.5
httpx==0.27.0
idna==3.3
importlib_metadata==8.5.0
isodate==0.6.1
Jinja2==3.1.4
jsonschema==4.22.0
jsonschema-path==0.3.3
jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.10.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
more-itertools==10.3.0
motor==3.5.0
msal==1.31.1
msal-extensions==1.2.0
multidict==6.0.4
nest-asyncio==1.6.0
numpy==1.25.0
openai==1.35.5
openapi-core==0.19.2
openapi-schema-validator==0.6.2
openapi-spec-validator==0.7.1
openpyxl==3.0.9
opentelemetry-api==1.29.0
opentelemetry-sdk==1.29.0
opentelemetry-semantic-conventions==0.50b0
packaging==24.1
pandas==1.4.0
parse==1.20.2
pathable==0.4.3
portalocker==2.10.0
prance==23.6.21.0
psycopg==3.1.9
psycopg2==2.9.6
pybars4==0.9.13
pycparser==2.21
pydantic==2.7.4
pydantic-settings==2.3.4
pydantic_core==2.18.4
PyJWT==2.3.0
PyMeta3==0.5.1
pymongo==4.8.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==1.0.1
pytz==2021.3
pywin32==306; sys_platform == 'win32'
PyYAML==6.0
referencing==0.35.1
regex==2024.5.15
requests==2.32.3
rfc3339-validator==0.1.4
rpds-py==0.18.1
ruamel.yaml==0.18.6
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.8
scipy==1.10.1
semantic-kernel==1.1.2
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.1
soupsieve==2.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
timedelta==2020.12.3
tqdm==4.65.0
typing_extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2021.5
urllib3==1.26.8
Werkzeug==3.0.3
whitenoise==6.1.0
wrapt==1.17.0
yarl==1.9.2
zipp==3.21.0


If possible, Share your GitHub repo?

I am new to github and web development. Is there anything specific you want to see that I can answer?

Please provide your requirements.txt file here.

Provide minimal code to reproduce the issue.

Updated the post with content from requirements.txt. Please take a look.

Try to update your packages.

Try to Create new Azure Web app with Python 3.11 version.

Cached pip packages might cause problems. In your GitHub Actions workflow, try clearing the cache: in yaml try-
Copy code

name: Clear pip cache
run: pip cache purge


yeah, I have the stmt to clear cache in Yaml but still the same issue is consistently getting reported.

So after multiple long and failed deployments, I finally upgraded everything to work with Python 3.12 - including github actions, packages in requirements.txt and azure web app - and it worked....
